# How can I convert an observable to a maybe?

Tags: rx-java2

There are new convenience methods added to `rxjava2` added to accomplish a similar thing.

- toSingle() converts an `Observable` that emits a single item into a `Single` that emits that item
- toObservable() converts a `Single` into an `Observable` that emits the item emitted by the `Single` and then completes

How do can I convert an `Observable` to a `Maybe`?

(source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't directly convert an `Observable` into a `Maybe`, because it wouldn't know what to emit in that context: is it the first element? the last? the product of some processing to the elements?

You can, however, decide on that and do what you want:

```
final Observable<Boolean> sourceBooleans = Observable.just(true, true, false);
final Maybe<Boolean> firstMaybe = sourceBooleans.firstElement();
final Maybe<Boolean> lastMaybe = sourceBooleans.lastElement();
final Maybe<Boolean> secondMaybe = sourceBooleans.elementAt(1);

final Observable<Integer> sourceNumbers = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4);
final Maybe<Integer> firstEven = sourceNumbers
    .filter(it -> it % 2 == 0)
    .firstElement()
```

You can see what methods return `Maybe` in the `Observable` [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java)

Note that you can't go from `Observable` to `Single` directly either, without choosing what it should emit: there's no `toSingle` in the `Observable` class, but methods that return a `Single` instead (like `first()`, `last()`, etc.)

Comment: How to do `maybe -> observable`?

Comment: @Adi `Maybe`'s `toObservable` should be just fine to go that way

Comment: Wow that got lost in the large documentation. I actually want to convert `Maybe<Set<String>> to Observable<String>`. Any hint?

Comment: @Adi you should probably ask that on a separate question, as it's a bit unrelated and would requiere more explanation. Feel free to post a link to your new question here and I'll answer it